# Norton 2010 .rar false positive issue

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, norton-antivirus

I have a file which is in the .rar format and Norton keeps picking it up during a scan as a virus and only giving me the option in the drop down box of delete. I don't want to delete it and I don't want Norton to tell me every 15 mins to delete it (as i just press close and "leave unresolved issues").

So how can i make Norton 2010 just accept that this particular .rar file is fine?!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of Would be to simply look in the exclusions list in settings and see if you can just include that one file, if not, possibly exclude the whole directory if you have nothing critical in there / Do not use it as a staging folder for other activities.

(Going from the settings in a much older version of Norton, there may be something newer)

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. The directory is in the scan exclusions list, which seemed to work for about 6 hours but then it came back. So i added it to the Auto-protect exclusions list too- to no avail. 

Sorry, just read could be a bug in 2010-i'll try the hotfix and get back.

Comment: From what i've read in the forums it seems this is a common problem and also it could be an issue with the 2010 version (which the hotfix didnt fix for me) Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

like most IT security companies, Symantec has a facility where customers may submit suspicious files:

**[Upload a suspected infected file](https://submit.symantec.com/websubmit/retail.cgi)**

*If you're a 'Gold' customer, use this [link](https://submit.symantec.com/websubmit/gold.cgi) instead.*

the submission is secure and will be treated confidential. if this is indeed a false positive, the error will certainly be corrected with the next definition updates.

Edit: as a work-around, you may repack the archive with encryption (enable file header and name encryption), Norton shouldn't be able to scan within this archive.

Comment: Don't count on it!

Comment: not sure about Symantec but i can vouch for Avira, they have rectified an error with VoipStunt earlier this year within 24 hours with the next update.